# Set default value but result is null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Set up rates to have a default value = "0" but result is null.  The value for rates (which rates are added to the Rider.class) doesn't add to the table in Firebase like it should...

Any ideas how to fix would be greatly appreciated ....

**nav_header_home**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtStars"
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Home**

```
// properties:
Textview txtStars;

// onCreate:
View navigationHeaderView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
txtStars = navigationHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.txtStars);
txtStars.setText(String.format("%s", Common.currentUser.getRates()));
```

**MainActivity**

```
// showRegisterDialog() ...

// Register new user
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(),
                    edtPassword.getText().toString())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                            // Save user to db
                            Rider rider = new Rider();
                            rider.setRates("0");//<---- default value
```

**Home.java**

```
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_signOut) {
        signOut();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_updateInfo) {
        showUpdateInfoDialog();
    }

    return true;
}
```

In the **MainActivity** in the AutoLogin method ....
(because it has an auto login), also had to add;

```
 // fetch data an save to variable
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.user_rider_tbl)
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    Common.currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(Rider.class);

                                    waitingDialog.dismiss();

                                    Intent i = new Intent(RiderActivity.this,
                                            Home.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    finish();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                            });
```

When debugging, txtStars = null

Comment: Can you also post the class where you define your getter and setter methods, so we can see why it's being assigned a null value

Comment: @Aaron added Rider.class

Comment: One last thing, could you print screenshot or write the error log also so we can see exactly where it's pointing the error too :)

Comment: @Aaron I am not getting an error, just the result of the stars is showing null on my riders info in their profile, rather than the default value.  Added a pic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set the default value for the rate to be zero, then I would just set that value to zero when you are initializing the variable.

```
private String rates = "0";
```

Or you can set the default value in the constructor as follows:

```
public Rider() {this.rates = "0";}
```

That way the value of rates will always have a default value of zero, let me know how that works out! :)

Comment: Is everything else setting correctly with their respective default values?